# Jcoserver status changing to STOPPING (not STOPPED) when stop() is called

Tags: java, jco, sapjco3

I am using `SAPJco3.jar` for connecting to SAP using Java. However, when I am trying to stop my bridge, I get some error.

The code for disconnection is this :

```java
 public void tearDown() {
     log.info("tearDown() | Starting tear down ...");
     log.info("tearDown() | Stopping {} JCO servers ...", jcoServerList.size());
 
     System.out.printf("\ntearDown()| Stopping %s JCO servers ...", jcoServerList.size());
     System.out.println();
 
     for (JCoServer jcoServer : jcoServerList.values()) {
         try {
             
             jcoServer.stop();
             jcoServer.release();
 
         } catch (Exception e) {
             log.error("Failed to STOP JCO server {} e={}", jcoServer.getProgramID(), e.toString());
         }
     }
 
     jcoServerDataManager.clearAllData();
     jcoServerDataManager = null;
 
     log.info("tearDown() | Done with tear down!");
 }
```

The error `JCO_ERROR_CONCURRENT_CALL` I get is this :

> ```
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||SapSessionReferenceProvider| getCurrentSessionReference() | Retrieving current session reference ...
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||SapSessionReferenceProvider| getCurrentSessionReference() | Current session reference retrieved Ok (id: sap-session-Default:Test_Bridge_With_External_Test_SAP_JCO:Y3IV_3)
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||SapSessionReferenceProvider| getCurrentSessionReference() | Retrieving current session reference ...
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||SapSessionReferenceProvider| getCurrentSessionReference() | Current session reference retrieved Ok (id: sap-session-Default:Test_Bridge_With_External_Test_SAP_JCO:Y3IV_3)
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|ERROR||||||SapConnectionManagerImpl| clearConnectionContext() | Failed to end SAP context: {}
>  com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (132) JCO_ERROR_CONCURRENT_CALL: Concurrent call 
>        detected. Connection [13] currently used in another thread:
>        pool-2-thread-1 [100] in execute since 7999 ms. Current thread:
>        22184429@qtp-6003181-5 [67], action: release.
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ClientConnection.acquireBusyState(ClientConnection.java:185)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.PoolingFactory.releaseClient(PoolingFactory.java:655)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ConnectionManager.releaseClient(ConnectionManager.java:234)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.Context.endSequence(Context.java:497)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntime.endSequence(JCoRuntime.java:805)
>     at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoContext.end(JCoContext.java:97)
>     at com.zetes.crystal.sap.io.impl.SapConnectionManagerImpl.clearConnectionContext(SapConnectionManagerImpl.java:258)
>     at com.zetes.crystal.sap.io.impl.SapConnectionManagerImpl.closeSapConnection(SapConnectionManagerImpl.java:145)
>     at com.zetes.crystal.sap.io.impl.SapConnectionManagerImpl.tearDown(SapConnectionManagerImpl.java:76)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:270)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:162)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:140)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:462)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:480)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:462)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:430)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:831)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:794)
>     at com.zetes.crystal.setup.server.bridges.impl.BridgeManagementServiceImpl.stopBridge(BridgeManagementServiceImpl.java:614)
>     at com.zetes.crystal.setup.server.bridges.impl.BridgeManagementServiceImpl.stopBridge(BridgeManagementServiceImpl.java:340)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter.invokeMethodOnService(GWTRPCServiceExporter.java:148)
>     at org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter.processCall(GWTRPCServiceExporter.java:298)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter.handleRequest(GWTRPCServiceExporter.java:363)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:536)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:930)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:405)
>     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||SapUserManagementServiceImpl| SAP user <Y3IV_3> has been released
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||SapConnectionManagerImpl| tearDown() | Done with SAP connection manager tear down!
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||JcoServerConnectionFactory| tearDown() | Starting tear down ...
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||JcoServerConnectionFactory| tearDown() | Stopping 1 JCO servers ...
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|DEBUG||||||JcoServerConnectionFactory|  >> STATUS = ALIVE
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|DEBUG||||||JcoServerConnectionFactory| >> Stopping JCO Server :: 3IV_ZE9_CLNT_890_001
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||JcoServerConnectionFactory| JCO Server ProgID: 3IV_ZE9_CLNT_890_001 [10]       ALIVE ->   STOPPING
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,504|INFO ||||||JcoServerConnectionFactory| tearDown() | Done with tear down!
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,520|INFO ||||||CockpitServiceImpl| Cockpit harvester of the bridge [Default:Test_Bridge_With_External_Test_SAP_JCO] has been un-registered from Cockpit manager
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,520|INFO ||||||BridgeManagementServiceImpl| bridge [Test_Bridge_With_External_Test_SAP_JCO] from site [Default] has been stopped OK
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,520|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,520|INFO ||||||BridgeConfigurationPersiterImpl| Configuration for the bridge [Test_Bridge_With_External_Test_SAP_JCO] in site [Default] has been persisted OK
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,520|DEBUG||||||BridgeManagementServiceImpl| onApplicationEvent() | begin
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,536|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,567|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,567|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,583|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,676|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,676|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,676|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,692|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
>  2018-12-06 15:00:15,739|DEBUG||||||SimpleThreadPool| WorkerThread is shutting down
> ```

When I am trying to stop the bridge, already there are some connections alive for this bridge and the status of the jcoserver changes from ALIVE -> STOPPING and it never goes to STOPPED.
If there are no connections attached to the server, it goes to the status STOPPED without any problem.

Could any one please provide any direction for this problem?
Is there any way I can forcefully stop the bridge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your custom `SessionReferenceProvider` implementation has a bug, namely returning the same session ID in multiple threads simultaneously.
Do you really need an own `SessionReferenceProvider`? Or is the default one from JCo maybe already sufficient? Maybe you can test your scenario without registering your own `SessionReferenceProvider` instance and see if it works.

And if not already using the latest JCo patch level, I would also recommend to update it in order to exclude already fixed bugs in JCo regarding this. SAP has just released JCo 3.0.19. See https://support.sap.com/jco .